# Split NSDate into year month date

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate

If I have a date like 04-30-2006
how can I split and get month, day and year

Alsois there any direct way of comparing the years ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you have to use NSDateComponents. Like this:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSUInteger componentFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:componentFlags fromDate:date];
NSInteger year = [components year];
NSInteger month = [components month];
NSInteger day = [components day];
```

> Alsois there any direct way of comparing the years ?

not built in. But you could write a category for it. Like this:

```
@interface NSDate (YearCompare)
- (BOOL)yearIsEqualToDate:(NSDate *)compareDate;
@end

@implementation NSDate (YearCompare)

- (BOOL)yearIsEqualToDate:(NSDate *)compareDate {
    NSDateComponents *myComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:self];
    NSDateComponents *otherComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:compareDate];
    if ([myComponents year] == [otherComponents year]) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

to split it is easy

```
NSString *dateStr = [[NSDate date] description];

NSString *fStr = (NSString *)[[dateStr componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *y = (NSString *)[[fStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"]objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *m = (NSString *)[[fStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"]objectAtIndex:1];
NSString *d = (NSString *)[[fStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"]objectAtIndex:2];
```

this will be easy to get things what you want basically .

Comment: Relying on those indicies is a dangerous practice. `NSDateComponents` is the way to go.

Comment: Not necessarily. If you get the date in a specific format than there is nothing wrong with splitting it in this way. Not everything requires the most general solution.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers so far assume you have an actual NSDate object, but in your post you say, "I have a date like 04-30-2006" which could be a string. If it is a string then Abizem's answer is the closest to what you want:

```
NSString* dateString = @"04-30-2006";
NSArray* parts = [dateString componentsSeparatedByString: @"-"];
NSString* month = [parts objectAtIndex: 0];
NSString* day = [parts objectAtIndex: 1];
NSString* year = [parts objectAtIndex: 2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, using `NSDateFormatter`:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM"];
NSString *month = [formatter stringFromDate:now];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd"];
NSString *day = [formatter stringFromDate:now];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];
NSString *year = [formatter stringFromDate:now];

[formatter release];
```

(code typed right here; caveat implementor)